# Font not rendering in FireFox using Tumblr

Tags: css, firefox, tumblr

I'm having this issue in the latest FireFox V28, its not rendering correctly. It shows up fine in Chrome but when I view my Tumblr page in FireFox it doesn't render correctly. I've checked my console and my response is ok in FireFox and not broken?

I've provided my CSS code that I've uploaded to my Tumblr page.

```
@font-face{
    font-family: 'MuseoSans500';
    src: url('http://static.tumblr.com/uxfhwz8/JUsn4gm1y/museosans-500.eot'); 
    src: url('http://static.tumblr.com/uxfhwz8/JUsn4gm1y/museosans- 500.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),  
    url('http://static.tumblr.com/uxfhwz8/vTfn4gm5f/museosans-500.woff') format('woff'), 
    url('http://static.tumblr.com/uxfhwz8/zEtn4gm2m/museosans-500.ttf') format('truetype'), 
    url('http://static.tumblr.com/uxfhwz8/HUxn4gm28/museosans-500.svg#MuseoSans500') format('svg'); 
}

@font-face{
    font-family: 'MuseoSans700';
    src: url('http://static.tumblr.com/uxfhwz8/aURn4gm2w/museosans-700.eot'); 
    src: url('http://static.tumblr.com/uxfhwz8/aURn4gm2w/museosans-700.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
    url('http://static.tumblr.com/uxfhwz8/cMgn4gm3i/museosans-700.woff') format('woff'), 
    url('http://static.tumblr.com/uxfhwz8/Z0tn4gm39/museosans-700.ttf') format('truetype'), 
    url('http://static.tumblr.com/uxfhwz8/g47n4gm84/museosans-700.svg#MuseoSans700') format('svg'); 
}

@font-face{
    font-family: 'MuseoSans900';
    src: url('http://static.tumblr.com/uxfhwz8/W3Xn4gm3u/museosans-900.eot'); 
    src: url('http://static.tumblr.com/uxfhwz8/W3Xn4gm3u/museosans-900.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
    url('http://static.tumblr.com/uxfhwz8/iYcn4gm4c/museosans-900.woff') format('woff'), 
    url('http://static.tumblr.com/uxfhwz8/egnn4gm48/museosans-900.ttf') format('truetype'), 
    url('http://static.tumblr.com/uxfhwz8/6tMn4gm44/museosans-900.svg#MuseoSans900') format('svg'); 
}
```

Sorry about that here are some screenshots.

**This is the firefox version.**

http://i1066.photobucket.com/albums/u401/Fernando_Abel_Gudino/Screenshots/ScreenShot2014-04-23at114617AM_zps9431f0b4.png

**This is the Chrome version.**
http://i1066.photobucket.com/albums/u401/Fernando_Abel_Gudino/Screenshots/ScreenShot2014-04-23at114655AM_zps3187e395.png

Thanks,

- Abel

Comment: What do you mean by: "it doesn't render correctly"? Please share some details on the problem.

Comment: Check the console to see if its displaying a CORS issue, related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13921876/base64-font-encoding-for-tumblr-on-firefox

Comment: Please give some detail on how font is not rendering correctly in Firefox V28.

Comment: Please see above post just updated it with screenshots.